# What does "metadiscursive framework" mean?

Tags: phrases, homework

In their article "The language of text-messaging" (which appeared in 2009, in S.C. Herring, D. Stein & T. Virtanen (eds), *Handbook of the Pragmatics of CMC*. Berlin and New York: Mouton do Gruyter.), Crispin Thurlow and Michele Poff use the phrase,

> Given this modest but growing body of research, it is surprising that
>   public and policy-level discourse about text-messaging continues to
>   fixate on its deleterious impact on literacy and standard language use
>   -- especially of young people (see Thurlow 2006, 2007). No review of the literature on texting would, however, be complete without briefly
>   considering this broader metadiscursive framework.

I googled this term "metadiscursive framework" and only got 8 hits, so I think it is relatively uncommon. The term "metadiscursive" is referring to "metadiscourse" which is discussion about a discussion (or maybe, about discussion). So I have a hand waving idea of what this means, but I will need to introduce it to the reader in plain language (using the magic of apposition).

Any ideas how I could define this term in plain language?

**UPDATE**

Here are some more examples of the term's usage:

From "Middle English medical recipes: a metadiscursive approach", [here](http://www.thefreelibrary.com/Middle+English+medical+recipes%3a+a+metadiscursive+approach.-a0249463650).

> The first person singular pronoun is associated with authorial
>   identity while its plural counterpart is connected to the concept of
>   community. This is essential in the metadiscursive framework as it
>   points at the idea of communication as always accounted for in terms
>   of social contexts.

From "The Moral Resonance of Arab Media", [here](http://books.google.ca/books?id=qEa3rA3tQ-sC&pg=PA98&lpg=PA98&dq=%22metadiscursive%20framework%22&source=bl&ots=eUoTz-rzJ6&sig=Mhe3B68Zz_Ys-4adApZN3LSQoBc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6-P0T4fVCseprQGXx-DWAw&ved=0CEkQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22metadiscursive%20framework%22&f=false).

> As I suggest, genre provides a way to discuss the organization of talk
>   and poetry -- a "metadiscursive" framework -- as poets and signers
>   build consensus over the kind of community that is best able to
>   address the needs at hand.

Comment: Got a link for the article, or at least a reference? Context makes a difference with theoretical papers like this. Is it, for instance, criticism or linguistics? That can make a **big** difference in what words mean.

Comment: You're misquoting the article. It says [No review of the literature on texting 
would be complete, however, without briefly considering this broader **metalinguistic** framework.](http://faculty.washington.edu/thurlow/papers/thurlow&poff(2010).pdf) Besides which (as should be clear from the word **"this"**), the exact thing being referred to as a *"metalinguistic framework"* is given in the preceding sentence. So here, it means educationalists and others worrying about texting having a negative impact on literacy.

Comment: @JohnLawler I've included a reference, unfortunately I couldn't find a link to the publication itself. As the FumbleFingers rightly points out, that word is replaced in the 2011 publication by "metalinguistic" (this doesn't change my question). I'll include more of the surrounding context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers that is from the 2011 version, sorry I should have been more specific. However, I'm not interested in the referent, since as you've observed, I have the paper right in front of me. I'm interested in the answer to my question, which is 'What does “metadiscursive framework” mean?'

Comment: @user23150: That reference was scarcely necessary, given I'd already given a link to the text in searchable pdf format. If you're having trouble with this level of academic language, I suggest you just read something different.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't understand your comment.

Comment: In practice, it doesn't make much difference which word was used because the *meaning* is - as I said - given by the preceding sentence. But it's only two sentences in to a section entitled *"2.4.  Metalinguistic contexts"*, so I think we can safely say you've either misquoted or your copy is faulty.

Comment: ...anyway - typesetting errors notwithstanding - I think this question is too localised.

Comment: @FumbleFingers hmm... OK I will provide more examples! I do have a hand-waving grasp of the meaning: I haven't had to stop reading. I'd like to be able to use the term myself, though. As a language learner I agree with you: If someone points at something and calls it "an apple", my going on to ask "yes, but what IS 'an apple', might only serve to cause confusion. On the other hand, as someone who is seeking a deeper understanding of what seems to be a dense term, I think I will need more detail.

Comment: @user23150: If by *"as a language learner"* you mean you're not a native speaker, then as I suggested, you should probably look for less challenging texts. Both words have general-purpose dictionary definitions, so I really don't see why you've asked this question at all. The specific meaning in context is given by the very text you quote - asking us to explore other possible shades of meaning in other contexts seems pointlessly open-ended.

Comment: @FumbleFingers sorry for the confusion: I meant to create sympathy for your position by saying that 'as someone who has learned languages, I feel such and such'. No English is definitely my native language. Maybe I am confused about the nature of this site: I thought that I could come and ask a question about a term like this and get an answer from a community.

Comment: _"The term 'metadiscursive' is referring to 'metadiscourse' which is discussion about a discussion (or maybe, about discussion). So I have a hand waving idea of what this means, but I will need to introduce it to the reader in plain language (using the magic of apposition).  Any ideas how I could define this term in plain language?"_  You said it yourself: it's "a discussion about discussions" ~ what's wrong with that?

Comment: @J.R. yeah metadiscourse is discussion about discussion, and a framework is like... scalfolding? (I mean, we use frameworks in computer programming, but I expect this differs slightly from the way sociolinguists use the term). Are you suggesting that, taken together, they just mean 'scaffolding for discussion about discussion'?

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize "framework" needed clarification for the layman, too.  If that's the case, I might say, "We are going to build a _metadiscursive framework_, that is, we will establish a structure that will let us discuss and analyze the nature of discussion" ~ or something like that.

Comment: @J.R. I think that is an answer to my question! I would probably accept that answer... if someone posted it.

Comment: This Q. rightly belongs on the writersSE. I might really like to answer it if posted there.

Answer (score 1):

From your original post:

> The term 'metadiscursive' is referring to 'metadiscourse' which is discussion about .. discussion. So I have a hand waving idea of what this means, but I will need to introduce it to the reader in plain language. Any ideas how I could define this term in plain language?

As you said, **metadiscursive** simply describes a *discussion about discussions;*  that seems to describe the word in a fairly straightforward way.  If you feel like **framework** needs clarification as well, you could say something along the lines of:

> We are going to build a *metadiscursive framework*, that is, we will establish a structure that will let us discuss and analyze the nature of discussion.

Maybe that would do the trick?

Answer (score 1):

> No review of the literature on texting would, however, be complete without briefly considering this broader metadiscursive framework.

I understand this sentence as an academic way to say "A review of this literature on texting should include a look at its context" (the context of the literature!).

**The "metadiscourse" in this context is the literature (i.e. communication/discourse) on texting (i.e. communication/discourse).**

The "framework" is a polished word for "context" here.

**In your example, "Metadiscursive framework" is an academic (and shorter) way of saying "the context of the literature on texting*".**

This gives us:

> No review of the literature on texting would, however, be complete without briefly considering this broader *context of the literature on texting*.

It is that simple, once you wrap your head around it, which is not simple...

Comment: In "The Moral Resonance of Arab Media", "metadiscursive framework" clearly means "a framework (a place) for discussing talk and poetry". Speaking about communication is always "metadiscourse", and the "framework" is whatever surrounds it/gives it room.

Answer (score 0):

A "metadiscursive framework" is a framework (that is, a structure that supports some activity), which supports or enables metadiscourse.

In the passage by Thurlow and Poff, they are perhaps referring to the research that enables linguists to talk about the discussion surrounding texting messaging and its supposedly deleterious impact on language.

Comment: Even after giving this tentative answer, I still don't feel comfortable using the term 'metadiscursive framework' in my own writing, so I can't accept this as the final answer to my question.

Comment: The copy I linked to contains *Invariably, these **metalinguistic** - or **language ideological** - debates prioritize the belief that text messaging language has a negative impact.* a couple of sentences later. Does your version also change that to "metadiscursive"? I utterly fail to get this question. It's either a typesetting error or Lit. Crit.

Comment: I'd super-double-plus this answer...except it's not about ELU but about...something else entirely. What is 'friendship'? It's a fascinating question but not really about ELU topics.